# Error with matplotlib when running examples of scikit learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am recently learning python, and I came across a package called scikit learn where we can use python libraries and custom made codes to generate various plots. I am already have installed all the dependancies and then I have downloaded and installed the scikit learn but when I am trying to run the example codes I am getting the error in generating the plot.

code

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
boston = datasets.load_boston()
y = boston.target

# cross_val_predict returns an array of the same size as `y` where each entry
# is a prediction obtained by cross validated:
predicted = cross_val_predict(lr, boston.data, y, cv=10)

fig,ax = plt.subplots() ## error comes from calling the function plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y, predicted)
ax.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], 'k--', lw=4)
ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
fig.show()
```

Error

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 866, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1712, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Is this something to do with setting up the environmental variable? I am using python 2.7.3 and this package should work with it or doing I have to put the path or something? sorry am very new to python just quickly trying to figure out if I can use this package for generating plots quickly or not. Any help to get rid of this error is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a `scikit-learn` problem.  There is an issue creating the plots from `matplotlib`.  Are you sure that is installed correctly?

Comment: yes this is a problem of the matplotlib not the scikit-learn. I have installed installed in linux the scikit-learn using pip by the below command {pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn} , the installation did not have any problem. Then I am directly using the script from the examples to run them on python2.7.3 . I am importing the matplotlib in the script then there should not be problem right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to run your code on a distant machine (`ssh` maybe) or simply `matplotlib` is not well installed.

If you are in the first case, I would suggest to use `savefig` with the command `matplotlib.use('Agg')` that tells `matplotlib` to not use the default display. This will produce a `.png` file that you could import it to your home using `scp`:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from pylab import savefig
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
boston = datasets.load_boston()
y = boston.target

# cross_val_predict returns an array of the same size as `y` where each entry
# is a prediction obtained by cross validated:
predicted = cross_val_predict(lr, boston.data, y, cv=10)

fig,ax = plt.subplots() ## error comes from calling the function plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y, predicted)
ax.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], 'k--', lw=4)
ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')

# don't use fig.show()

savefig('FIGURE_NAME.png') # savefig from matplotlib
```

Comment: yes exactly I am using in ssh cluster. But does not the matplotlib libraries directly get installed once you download scikit-learn? it should be so that you just need to import the libraries when you run the script

Comment: yes `matplotlib` is installed but to show the plot, python can't find where to display it :-)

Comment: so how should i change it? I need to put the path in the plt.subplots() right?

Comment: but now am having some other issues. `ax.scatter(y, predicted)
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x35bc0d0>
>>> ax.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], 'k--', lw=4)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x35bc050>]
>>> ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x3432210>
>>> ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x3435c10>
>>> savefig('FIGURE_NAME.png')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'savefig' is not defined`  . why is this error coming up ?

Comment: Sorryn you need to add `from paylab import savefig`

Comment: is it paylab or something else?

Comment: no it's `pylab` (It's already in the code) it was a typing error in the comment

Comment: yes I changed the code and it works now. thanks a lot, I generated the figure